# I have problem when i start android studio and rebuild project not work good

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-sdk-tools

After Run Android Studio And Build Gradel I Have This Error And I Can't Fix This.
I'm Checked jdk instal And Sdk Instaletion But I Can't Find Way To Fix Error.

```
Cannot resolve class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
ERROR:C:\Users\Sina\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e0be1e4ebe8d827889716686ce55c5f3\transformed\material-1.4.0\res\layout\material_clock_display.xml:18: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintTop_toTopOf (aka com.example.sinasaadi:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf) not found.
    ERROR:C:\Users\Sina\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e0be1e4ebe8d827889716686ce55c5f3\transformed\material-1.4.0\res\layout\material_clock_period_toggle.xml:18: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintStart_toEndOf (aka com.example.sinasaadi:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf) not found.
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
ERROR:C:\Users\Sina\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e0be1e4ebe8d827889716686ce55c5f3\transformed\material-1.4.0\res\layout\material_clock_display.xml:18: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintTop_toTopOf (aka com.example.sinasaadi:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf) not found.
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQgzk.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android studio go to file -> invalidate Caches. And try restarting studio.

Comment: i'm doing tihs soloution but it's not work and i have a new errors

Comment: Thank You alot for your answer but i had to delet all file of android studio shuch as local location hard path as .gradel, .google, sdks , Jdk and all of neccery tools for android and rrinstal android and fix my problem.

Comment: Sorry for this problem. The source of some problems is jdk, sdk etc. It may be due to missing such files or the file extension. The exact solution is as you did. you're right.